# How to make validation for a textbox that accepts only comma(,) & digit in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website. I am using C# corresponding to Visual Studio 2008. I want to make a text box that accept only numbers & comma(,).
For example,

```
-919981424199,78848817711,47171111747
```

or there may be a single number like `919981424199`.

I was able to do one thing. My text box is only containing a number by using this regular expression validation. In its property->Validation Expression I wrote "[0-9]+".
This is working, but now my requirement is to send bulk SMS, and each number is separated by (,).
I tried a lot, but I am not getting the answer. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "," to your regular expression. From memory I think it should be:

```
"[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*"
```

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/p/1370139/2861287.aspx)

To break the input into a list of numbers use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) with the comma as the delimiter:

```
string[] numbers = string.split(input, ",");
```

Then loop over the `numbers` array sending your SMS to each.